# SQL error, (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After an update of Visual Studio 2022 to v17.2.2, I suddenly get an error in my ASP.NET app, that a virtual class cannot insert into SQL database because the class does not allow nulls. Before the update I was not getting this error.

This is the model a use

```
public class Member
{       
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }      
    public string MemberImage { get; set; }
    
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } = new();
}
```

I need the last virtual property to get all members from the database of a the `Team` model from the `MemberRepository`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Member>> GetAllMembersByTeamId(int TeamId)
{
    var result = await dbContext.Members
                                .Include(t => t.Team)
                                .Where(t => t.TeamId == TeamId)
                                .ToListAsync();

    if (result != null)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else 
        return null;
}
```

And with the a `MemberRepository` I store it into the database:

```
public class MemberRepository : IMemberRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext dbContext;

    public MemberRepository(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
   
    public async Task<Member> AddMember(Member obj)
    {
        await dbContext.Members.AddAsync(obj);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I ask for the team I want to add the member with:

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Team = await TeamsRepository.GetTeamById(int.Parse(Id));
}
```

and fired it up with the EditForm, OnValidSubmit.

```
public async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    ConfirmationTitle = StaticString.ConfirmationTitle;
    ConfirmationMessage = StaticString.ConfirmationMessage;

    Member.TeamId = int.Parse(Id);

    await MemberRepository.AddMember(Member);
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/adminpage");
}
```

I'm confused, is it because the update or is something else, because I get the error also now in the previous made ASP.NET application.

Why this approach? I learned it of Kudvenkat from this site: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-model-classes/

This is the error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

This is the error i get:

blazor.server.js:1 [2022-06-02T13:13:22.000Z] Error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Class', table 'Tjoba-Server.dbo.Teams'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
The statement has been terminated.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__188_0(Task`1 result) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:2df86c5d-9cee-4c70-ad12-ebb86a036fe9
Error Number:515,State:2,Class:16
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at DataAcces.Data.MemberRepository.AddMember(Member obj) in C:\VsProjects\Tjoba_Server\DataAccess\Data\MemberRepository.cs:line 21
at Tjoba.Pages.Admin.AddMember.HandleValidSubmit() in C:\VsProjects\Tjoba_Server\Tjoba\Pages\Admin\AddMember.razor:line 207
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
log @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2022-06-02T13:13:22.001Z] Information: Connection disconnected.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
at bt.send (blazor.server.js:1:52004)
at kt._sendMessage (blazor.server.js:1:68639)
at kt._sendWithProtocol (blazor.server.js:1:68680)
at kt.send (blazor.server.js:1:68788)
at Object.beginInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.server.js:1:131279)
at w (blazor.server.js:1:2164)
at C.invokeMethodAsync (blazor.server.js:1:4014)
at blazor.server.js:1:11516
at T (blazor.server.js:1:11694)
at I (blazor.server.js:1:11485)
```

I get with a try catch block the same error message
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Class', table 'TjobaServer.dbo.Teams'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Strange is that I only want to insert a member to the database with a TeamId, but nothing to the table Teams.

I figured out and found the solution.
Have added an if block with the Entity unchanged code into the AddMember Task in the MemberRepository:

```
 public async Task<Member> AddMember(Member member)
    {
        if (member.Team != null)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(member.Team).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        var result =  await dbContext.Memberss.AddAsync(member);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return result.Entity;         
       
    }
```

Comment: can we please see the whole error message, plus the stack trace, where is it being raised?

Comment: The virtual keyword shouldn't be needed, as this allows for lazy loading. However you're making use of an Include when you're querying for all members based on TeamId. 
As @pm100 mentioned a copy of the entire error message would be more helpfull indeed.

Comment: [mre], where is the "minimal" in this case ?

Comment: This was my first question on this forum, Thought to give enough information for more clarity. Sorry for my ignorance.